# How to keep footer in joomla template sticked to the bottom?

Tags: css, joomla

I have developed template for Joomla 3. What I want to stick footer in the bottom when content is less than height of monitor.
Here is example http://bmsc.tfei.info/en/library-en 
The footer jumps to up when content is less.
I want to keep it in the bottom if content is less.
Is it possible to do in css without using jQuery?
If yes can you show me example or direction in my css where I should make changes.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

You may refer this post-

http://www.cssstickyfooter.com/using-sticky-footer-code.html

You need to keep #header and #mainbody inside #wrap and apply the CSS accordingly.

Hope this may help.